# How to use RIGHT OUTER JOIN with GROUP BY in SQl Server 2017?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want use ROJ in sql server with filter date but not work, i mean must return data table round null but not return how to fix problem ?

> SQL Code

```
SELECT Lines.Target,  COUNT(Round.ID) AS cnt
FROM Round RIGHT OUTER JOIN Line as Lines
on Round.Line = Lines.ID
WHERE Lines.Company = 20 AND 
CAST(Round.System_Date AS DATE) BETWEEN 
CAST('2019-03-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2019-03-01' AS DATE)
GROUP BY Lines.Target
```

> with out filter date code work
>
> Must return =>

```
Target   cnt
------  -----
7         0
9         0
15        0
```

Comment: I can't see anything "wrong" with that  with that code, what do you mean my it didn't "work"? Guessing it's because of the `WHERE`. Why not use a `LEFT JOIN` and have your `WHERE` clause on the table `round` in your `ON`? Why do you want to use a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: Most people find it easier to understand `main table left join optional data` instead of `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: Update My quotation try see again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to `LEFT JOIN`. Move outer table condition from `WHERE` to `ON` to get true outer join result:

```
SELECT Lines.Target, COUNT(Round.ID) AS cnt
FROM Line as Lines
LEFT OUTER JOIN Round
    on Round.Line = Lines.ID
    AND CAST(Round.System_Date AS DATE) BETWEEN
            CAST('2019-03-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2019-03-01' AS DATE)
WHERE Lines.Company = 20
GROUP BY Lines.Target
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres no `BETWEEN` required as its the same date you are searching for and make sure record exists for that specific date 
Plus,

If you want the rounds table data being the master table then why you are using right outer join  use `Left Outer Join`

Comment: use Left Outer Join but not any thing change